# How to fix "Unable to instantiate JDBC driver" Flyway command line error?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, command-line, flyway

I'm new to Flyway. I'm using Flyway 3.2.1 on windows 64bit and just tried the command line tool with my local Oracle database installation (11g). I'm getting the following error:

ERROR: Unable to instantiate JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

What did I do wrong? In flyway.conf I configured my jdbc url and also username and password.

Thanks in advance
Matze

Comment: Ahhhh - it's stupid error by myself! The config file says: # * = driver must be downloaded and installed in /drivers manually. So after copying the oracle jdbc jar to the drivers sub directory it now works fine!

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved. For Oracle you have to put the jdbc driver jar in the drivers sub directory.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle).

**In summary:** Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html and choose the required Oracle JDBC driver version. Then download the "ojdbc6.jar" file and move it into the `drivers` folder beneath where Flyway is installed. The next time you run Flyway this should be picked up automatically.